# Text To Speech with SAPI: Custom Language

Tags: c#, sapi

I'm from Greece and I want to make an application which will use SAPI to interact with the user, but I can't find a way to change the language of SAPI from English to Greek.

My OS is by default Greek & English, and I have SAPI SDK installed; the Greek Language is supported by SAPI.

The problem is that SAPI doesn't automatically recognise the language passed to it, and reverts to saying the individual letters *one-by-one*.

Here is the code I'm using, with English text:

```
using SpeechLib;

SpVoice voice = new SpVoice();
voice.Speak("Pdf File Successfully Installed", SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync);
voice.WaitUntilDone(30000);
```

This works, but when I pass Greek text to the function (eg `"Να ενα κειμενο"`), I see the problem occur.

Comment: So you're having trouble with the Text To Speech side, rather than the recognition side?

Comment: @JamesThorpe I dont really know whose fault is..:/

Comment: You could use Speech XML to note the languages inline...

Comment: Alternatively you may want to set the Voice to a greek voice.

Comment: @Ben Thanks for answering Ben.. Can you explain in more depth how can I do that?

Comment: @CaptainLemon I reworded your question to clarify it's about the Text To Speech side - feel free to re-edit or revert it if I've done so incorrectly.

Comment: I don't believe that Microsoft ships a Greek TTS voice in Windows.  When you say "The Greek Language is supported by SAPI", what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a language by passing SSML to the `Speak` API, and including the `xml:lang` attribute.

For example this should work:

```
SpVoice voice = new SpVoice();
voice.Speak(
"<speak version='1.0' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xml:lang='el-GR'>"
+ "Να ενα κειμενο"
+ "</speak>",
 SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync|SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFIsXML);
voice.WaitUntilDone(30000);
```

You can also switch language mid-speech. The documentation has this example:

```
<speak version="1.0"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis"
  xml:lang="en-US">

   For English, press 1.

   <voice xml:lang="fr-FR" gender="female"> 
   Pour le français, appuyez sur 2 </voice>

</speak>
```

For more, see here:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127898.aspx

Comment: Thanks so much Ben.Solution 1 seems to be pretty nice, but im getting an error while trying to run it

Comment: You are missing your close tag `</speak>`

Comment: Oh I'm so dump..I will give it a try,And I will reply soon!

Comment: As I have seen in Microsoft's site , can I use Lang ID in the SSML? Is this changing, the xml:lang="el-GR" tag. For example, instead of "el-GR", I shall use 408 (Greek Id lang) ?

Comment: Sorry yes, it should be "el" or maybe "el-GR" not "gr-GR". I don't know if you can use 408, sorry.